# How to use SCSS/SASS to increase animation-delay for concurrent divs

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to replicate the loading animation of the Windows 8 tiles. It seems that each tile has an animation delay which is slightly higher than its predecessor. I have been acheiving this currently by using nth-child in an inefficient way as you can see below. Does anyone know a way that I can achieve this in a more efficient manner that would cater for any number of divs?

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/bmvcu)

```
.results div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.results div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.results div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.results div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.results div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
}
.results div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.results div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.75s;
}
.results div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Since every CSS preprocessor outputs plain old CSS, I don't think it's possible to handle an infinite number of elements. Javascript, on the other hand...

Comment: I think it can with someone who knows how to use SASS - See this looks and say sequence http://thesassway.com/advanced/math-sequences-with-sass / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: The only way it would be possible would be if it can also be done in vanilla CSS. I'm sure you can do it if you are willing to accept that you must be explicit about how many elements there are. Upvoted, hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Maybe a mixture of JS to work out the number of divs then check the previous divs animation delay and add a certain amount of time to that number?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use a for loop in Sass to do this like so:

```
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
  .results div:nth-child(#{$i}) { animation-delay: $i * 0.25s; }
}
```

Then you can do it for any number of divs by making the 10 to what ever you need.

Comment: Can the 10 be 20 even if there are only 10?

Comment: http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/bmvcu - Iseem to be getting a syntax error with that solution?

Comment: the limit is simply telling the pre processor how many times to output that loop of css. it is unrelated to the html. you can make it 100 if you want

Answer (score 16):

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .results div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    -webkit-animation-delay:(#{$i*0.1s}); 
    animation-delay:(#{$i*0.1s}); 
  }
}
```

Better solution... I tested and it works ;)

Comment: Why is this a better solution?

Comment: seems `through` include `10` but `to` exclude

Answer (score 6):

I use this mixin:

```
@mixin delay($rule, $number, $value) {
  @for $i from 1 to ($number + 1) {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      -webkit-#{$rule}-delay: (#{$i*$value});
      #{$rule}-delay: (#{$i*$value});
    }
  }
}

.results div{
  @include delay(animation, 8, 0.25s);
}
```

This way you can re use it transitions too.