# animation-delay property isn't working in Sass for loop

Tags: css, animation, svg, sass, delay

I'm trying to delay when a group of elements' animations begin based on their index, so their animations start sequentially.

For an unindentifiable reason, it just isn't working:

https://jsfiddle.net/ctu7tcru/

I've identified that:

- The elements are being selected fine (note how the `background` is changing)
- It doesn't have anything to do with SVG
- It doesn't have anything to do with the animation being infinite

Seemingly, it just doesn't work when you try to change the `animation-delay` property in the loop. It works when it's outside the loop and doesn't work (under any circumstances) when it's in it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612286/4833461) answer appears to be exactly the same, but I copied it and it didn't work. Iunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JackHasaKeyboard, it's an issue of specificity.

```
#prog {
  height: 76px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  .dot {
    animation: pulse 1.6s infinite;
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  #prog .dot:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: $i * 1.6s;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Add the `#prog` id to your loop and it should work.

Here's a fork of your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqk8dxhx/2/).