# Sass for loop assigns same index to each element

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I want to apply an animation to different divs. Each of them should get their own animation delay.

There are many tutorials online ([Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612125/how-to-use-scss-sass-to-increase-animation-delay-for-concurrent-divs)) and I followed them closely, but for some reason the animation delay remains the same for every div.

I have the following for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
    #contact-grid .contact-item .contact-link:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        @include textShakeAnimation($delay: #{$i}s);
    }
}
```

With this animation mixin:

```
@mixin textShakeAnimation($delay) {
    transform-origin: center;
    animation-name: text-shake;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes text-shake {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    2% {transform: rotate(5deg);}
    4% {transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    6% {transform: rotate(5deg);}
    8% {transform: rotate(-5deg);}
    10% {transform: rotate(5deg);}
    12% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="contact-grid">
    <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="contact-header-wrapper">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter contact-icon fa-2x"></i>
            <h3 class="contact-heading">Twitter</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="contact-text">Check us out on Twitter!</p>
        <div class="contact-link">
            <a href="#">@kitis_kitties</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

What is strange to me is, that despite the loop going from 1 to 5, when I inspect the divs, the animation delay for every div is 3. So right at the midpoint of the indexes.

But the strangest thing is, that the generated CSS has the correct animation delays:

```
#contact-grid .contact-item .contact-link:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation-name: text-shake;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
...
```

The animation itself is working well, but the delays are not applied correctly.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing? Or at least some pointers in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what nth-child does. The 3s delay works on .contact-link because it is the third child of it's parent. Which elements need the animation applying?

Comment: @dantheman Aaah yeah that makes sense. Thanks for clearing up that confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is due to incorrect targetting of css,
`:nth-child` should be on `.contact-item` instead of `.contact-link`

```
//your code
    @for $i from 1 through 5 {
        #contact-grid .contact-item .contact-link:nth-child(#{$i}) {   
            @include textShakeAnimation($delay: #{$i}s);
        }
    }

//corrected code
        @for $i from 1 through 5 {
            #contact-grid .contact-item:nth-child(#{$i}) .contact-link{  //this line
                @include textShakeAnimation($delay: #{$i}s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you so much.
I didnt realize that I can add more classes to the selector after the :nth-child. I dont know why I assumed that that wasnt a thing.